# How to display different trace names than stated in the legend if I hover over in Plotly?

Tags: angular, charts, plotly, plotly.js

How can I display different trace names than stated in the legend if I hover over it?

Currently I push my config like this:

```
  ...
  const chart_entry = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    type: 'scatter',
    name: legendName
  };
  this.graph.data.push(chart_entry);
  ...
```

In this way, however, both in the legend and when hovering over a line the same name from the legend is addressed (legendName variable).

But I want the hover to have an individual name.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `hovertemplate`option: https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scatter-hovertemplate

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'legend name 1',
  hovertemplate: '%{y}<extra>hover name 1</extra>'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'legend name 2',
  hovertemplate: '%{y}<extra>hover name 2</extra>'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {}, {});
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you :)

Comment: @mit A nice question with a good and accepted answer. Yet no upvotes? Here, have som upvotes you greedy ingrates =)